# MySQL: How to optimize result of SUM of fields?

Tags: mysql, optimization, sum, query-optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT name, SUM(count_1 + count_2 + count_3 + count_4 + count_5 + count_6) AS Total
FROM my_table
```

Is there a way to add these values `count_1 + count_2 + count_3 + count_4 + count_5 + count_6` and so on..  more efficiently? MySQL keeps crashing for me when I add huge numbers of fields.

Comment: Why do you have so many fields? That's usually a sign that the schema isn't properly normalized.

Comment: cast it to `BIGINT`

Comment: You understand that `SUM()` is for aggregating across multiple rows, right? You don't need it if you just want to add fields in one row at a time.

Comment: @Barmar yeah cause the 'count_1' up there really represents time of the day and I want to store data per time of day so I have like 23 of those fields. Im curious if there's another way to add these?

Comment: You can use `SUM(count_1) + SUM(count_2) ...` but I think that would be less efficient.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the error? Or is the DB server crashing?

Comment: Normalise your schema. 3 columns: name \*, time \*, value, where \* = (component of) a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Barmar I'm not getting an error. MySQL workbench is not responding and freezes whenever I try to execute the query but then again it might be a problem with my system itself

Comment: How many rows are there in the table? It might just be taking a long time to add all the rows.

Comment: Does it "freeze" when using the mysql commandline tool?

Comment: Why are we entertaining this appalling design?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether the db design is right or wrong if you use an aggregation function you should use group by

```
SELECT name, SUM(count_1 + count_2 + count_3 + count_4 + count_5 + count_6) AS Total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name
```